# Search a webpage and grab certain data in Python 3

Tags: python, html, parsing

Im trying to get the text from a webpage with Python 3.3 and then search through that text for certain strings. When I find a matching string I need to save the following text. For example I take this page: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Prophecy
and I need to save the text after each category (card text, rarity, etc) in the card info.
Currently Im using beautiful Soup but get_text causes a UnicodeEncodeError and doesnt return an iterable object. Here is the relevant code:

```
urlStr = urllib.request.urlopen(
    'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=' + cardName
    ).read()

htmlRaw = BeautifulSoup(urlStr)

htmlText = htmlRaw.get_text

for line in htmlText:
    line = line.strip()
    if "Converted Mana Cost:" in line:
        cmc = line.next()
        message += "*Converted Mana Cost: " + cmc +"* \n\n"
    elif "Types:" in line:
        type = line.next()
        message += "*Type: " + type +"* \n\n"
    elif "Card Text:" in line:
        rulesText = line.next()
        message += "*Rules Text: " + rulesText +"* \n\n"
    elif "Flavor Text:" in line:
        flavor = line.next()
        message += "*Flavor Text: " + flavor +"* \n\n"
    elif "Rarity:" in line:
        rarity == line.next()
        message += "*Rarity: " + rarity +"* \n\n"
```

Comment: have you done a dir on html.text.  I am suprised - though not very knowledgable about BS that the method does not require parens.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with BeautifulSoup any more but I ran this code - not to give you a complete answer but to point you in the right direction

```
import urllib
from lxml import html
mypage = urllib.urlopen('http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=264')
dir(mypage)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__repr__', 'close', 'code', 'fileno', 'fp', 'getcode', 'geturl', 'headers', 'info', 'next', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'url']
page = mypage.readlines()
len(page)
526
page[0]
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>\r\n'
string = ''.join([apage for apage in page])
tree = html.fromstring(string)
elements = [e for e in tree.iter()]
for e in elements:
    if 'cardtextbox' in e.values():
        e, e.text_content()
 (<Element div at 0x31a7ba0>, 'Enchant creature')
 (<Element div at 0x31a7bf8>, "Enchanted creature has protection from red. This effect doesn't remove Red Ward.")
```

I clearly do not know what I am doing but I was poking at it.

It seemed to me that the values you are trying to identify are values of attribute dictionaries and so I knew enough to figure out this much.  It would take some more poking at it to list all of the attributes you want to identify but I think this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an HTML page parser. There are many HTML page parsers which you can use eg.

- [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html)
- [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)
- [uTidy](http://utidylib.berlios.de/)
- [htql](http://htql.net/)

My recommendation would be to use lxml.